# Find icons in eclipse plugin

Tags: url, jar, eclipse-plugin, uri, bundle

I want to get the **os location** of an *icon* in my **Eclipse plug-in** and I use this code:

```java
URL fileURLIconChoose = bundle.getEntry("pluginIcons/iconConfirm.png");
String pathIconChoose = null;
try {
  pathIconChoose = FileLocator.resolve(fileURLIconChoose).toURI().getPath();
} catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
}
JButton confirm = new JButton(new ImageIcon(pathIconChoose));
```

When I run the code in *eclipse environment* it works fine but when I *export* my product and install it in Eclipse, it fails.

How to solve the problem of the loading of the icons? Is there another way to access the icons in the plug-in?

Comment: How does this fail?  Is there a stack trace?  Include the stack trace here.

Comment: There is no stack trace, because the error comes up when I launch it after installing...however `pathIconChoose` remains null and after doing some tests, the problem is when it is invoked `toURI().getPath()` on `FileLocator.resolve(fileURLIconChoose)`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `FileLocator.toFileURL(URL url)` API instead.

As you can see from the [javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/FileLocator.html#toFileURL%28java.net.URL%29) it will extract the contents of the file to the disk when you need to access it.

*re-worked code*:

```java
URL fileURLIconChoose = bundle.getEntry("pluginIcons/iconConfirm.png");
String pathIconChoose = null;
try {
  pathIconChoose = FileLocator.toFileURL(fileURLIconChoose).toURI().getPath();
} catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
}
JButton confirm = new JButton(new ImageIcon(pathIconChoose));
```

Comment: The problem remains....when i export plugin and try this on Eclipse, `pathIconChoose` remains null...

Comment: Also make sure that your build.properties in your plugins contains in the bin.includes the folder pluginIcons

Comment: Yes, I insert it into the build.includes in _plugin.xml_

Comment: Can you print the value of fileURLIconChoose and then also print the value of the FileLocator.toFileURL() URL to compare the two?

Comment: Yes through JOptionPane... **for** fileURLIconChoose _file:/C:/Program Files (x86)/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/848/1/.cp/pluginIcons/iconConfirm.png_ ;     **for** FileLocator.toFileURL is NULL